# Socket error 10053 is seen when fast (within 100 ms)recv and send is being done

Tags: sockets, visual-c++

Client is sending 1 byte of data after every 4 seconds of interval. once its receives the byte it acknowledge with 1 byte.

Some times on send error 10053 is seen.

```
    iResult = recv(sSocket, (char*)recvbuf, 1, 0);
        if(iResult > 0)
            {               

                setsockopt(sSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (const char*)&dwTime, 1);
                iResult = send(sSocket,(char*)&recvbuf,1,0);
                if(iResult <= 0)
                {
                      // WSAgetLasterrror() == 10053  
                }
             }
```

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: why are you typecasting the DWORD time and reading one byte?

Comment: The code does not show how you build the value of dwTime. Are you sure that you pass any useful value in `setsockopt`? Probably the low byte of the DWORD dwTime might by zero.

Comment: I've had some problems with my firewall which destroyed my sockets if communication became to quick... Try turning off you firewall/antivirus and check if your communication works.